# Should HttpMessageHandler use ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, synchronizationcontext

If I have an asynchronous call inside a HttpMessageHandler, should it use the .ConfigureAwait method e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handler to assign the MD5 hash value if content is present
/// </summary>
public class RequestContentMd5Handler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content == null)
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        await request.Content.AssignMd5Hash().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this line and if it is OK to have `ConfigureAwait(false)` on that line.

```
await request.Content.AssignMd5Hash().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

No, on the next line you call `SendAsync` with the Http Request. You can't switch threads and still have access to the correct http request context so you have to use `ConfigureAwait(true)` or omit the call to `ConfigureAwait` all together.

Comment: thanks rationale for the question was all the other topics around server-side code should always use ConfigureAwait(false) - I'll use ConfigureAwait(true) so we don't confuse it

Comment: How come? The correct HTTP request is being passed as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You should always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when the code after the awaited code doesn't need to get back to the context provided by the synchronization context.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handler to assign the MD5 hash value if content is present
/// </summary>
public class RequestContentMd5Handler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            await request.Content.AssignMd5Hash().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```